# Animating a 3D shape along path a (2D and 3D) parametric function curve [Update]

Tags: differential-equations, animation, modeling

I have a 3D object under the action of gravity field.The trajectory of path is a parabola.I would like to animate , as in the example GIF.

[image]

```
 {X, Z} = With[{V = 7.5, \[Gamma] = 60 Degree, g = 9.81}, 
 NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == 0, z''[t] == -g, x[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, 
 WhenEvent[z[t] < 0, TIME = t; "StopIntegration"],
 x'[0] == V*Cos[\[Gamma]], z'[0] == V*Sin[\[Gamma]]}, {x, z}, {t, 
 0, Infinity}]];

 Animate[
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{X[t], 0, Z[t]}, {t, 0, TIME}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-2, 2}, {-0.5, 3}}, Axes -> True, 
 Ticks -> None], 
 Graphics3D[{Darker[Green, 0.3], 
 Cuboid[{{-5, -2, -0.5}, {6, 2, -0.45}}], 
 GeometricTransformation[{White, Opacity[.6], 
 Cone[{{0, 0, -0.5}, {0, 0, 0.5}}, 0.5], Red, Opacity[0.8], 
 Sphere[{0, 0, 0.25}, 0.25]}, 
 Composition[TranslationTransform[{X[t], 0, Z[t]}], 
 RotationTransform[X'[t]/Z'[t], {0, 1, 0}]]]}, Boxed -> True, 
 SphericalRegion -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-2, 2}, {-0.5, 3}}, Axes -> True, 
 Ticks -> None, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 Background -> Lighter[Blue, 0.92]]], {{t, 0, "Time"}, 0, 
 TIME - 0.05, 0.01}, AnimationRunning -> False, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Movement of the object is a combination of linear  and rotational motion.
I would like to rotational movement was expressed as a function of:

> RotationTransform

**>**
**UPDATE**

For Y axis tangent trajectory is correct,but for Z and X is not.

```
 {X, Y, Z} = With[{
 g = 9.81,
 V = 8,
 \[Alpha] = 45 Degree,
 \[Gamma] = -20 Degree},
NDSolveValue[{
 x''[t] == 0,
 y''[t] == 0,
 z''[t] == -g,
 WhenEvent[z[t] < 0, TIME = t; "StopIntegration"],
 x[0] == 0,
 y[0] == 0,
 z[0] == 0,
 x'[0] == V*Cos[\[Alpha]],
 y'[0] == V*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Gamma]],
 z'[0] == V*Sin[\[Alpha]]*Cos[\[Gamma]]
 }, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10}]];


 Animate[Show[ParametricPlot3D[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}, {t, 0, TIME}], 
 Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[{Yellow, Opacity[0.4], 
 Cone[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0}}, 0.5], Red, 
 Sphere[{0, 0, -0.20}, 0.25]}, 
 Composition[TranslationTransform[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}],
 RotationTransform[ArcTan[Z'[t], Y'[t]], {1, 0, 0}],
 RotationTransform[ArcTan[Z'[t], X'[t]], {0, 1, 0}],
 RotationTransform[ArcTan[X'[t], Y'[t]], {0, 0, 1}]]]],
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 7}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 3}}, Ticks -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}],
 {{t, 0, "Time"}, 0, TIME}, AnimationRunning -> False, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

I tried with function:

> FrenetSerretSystem

I nothing invented.

[image]

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/5603104/353410

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `X'[t]/Z'[t]`:

[image]

This is not the angle of rotation that you need. What you need is `ArcTan[Z'[t],X'[t]]`, which looks like this

[image]

If you change that in your code, you get the desired result.

[image]